# yii2 RESTFUL API browser blocked by CORS policy

Tags: react-native, api, yii2, request, cors

I have a problem, when I use:
https://github.com/sirinibin/Yii2-RESTful-API-with-OAuth2?fbclid=IwAR1i5XhcRIov2iT9HPJErVd_FjnYfVoYL5AREOid8QmdDOjmI7K1d-GKMIk

and it works fine, but from browser (fetch from reactNative) I have error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNRbS.jpg)

and

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q27k.jpg)

how can I add OPTIONS to all my requests?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved with:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/Cors.php#L111

in Cors.php beforeAction add:

```
    if ($this->request->isOptions && $this->request->headers->has('Access-Control-Request-Method')) {
        // it is CORS preflight request, respond with 200 OK without further processing
        $this->response->setStatusCode(200);
        return false;
    }
```

thanks Leandro Gehlen

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add following lines to your CORS filter configuration at [RestController.php](https://github.com/sirinibin/Yii2-RESTful-API-with-OAuth2/blob/master/backend/controllers/RestController.php)

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
'Allow' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
```

In the end, it should be something similar to:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Allow' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => null,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => []
            ]

        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```